# Развитие, разбитое по моментам, а не растянутое во времени

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как назвать развитие, рост чего-либо, хар-ся паузами и всплесками? Например, человек начинает изучать хореографическое искусство и спустя время в один день вдруг осознает подвижность, поворотливость своего тела - достигает "следующей ступени ощущений". Затем - пауза, тренироки, и в один миг (день, неделю) - чувство собственной грации, невесомости, внезапный подъем.

Толчкообразное, ступенчатое развитие (рост, динамика)?

Comment: 1. Хар-ся — это за что так-то слово резать? 2. Почему всюду чёрточки, а не тире?

Answer (score 1):

Зигзагообразный, пунктирный, волнообразный, дисперсный.

**[дисперсный](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)**

> *книжн.* рассеянный, раздробленный ◆ Официально к коренным малочисленным народам Российского Севера отнесены 30 народов,
> проживающих на территориях 27 субъектов Российской Федерации, их
> расселение имеет дисперсный характер, а историческая территория их
> проживания занимает 64 % территории страны. «ТЭК и этноценозы севера»
> // «Жизнь национальностей», 2004 г. (цитата из Национального корпуса
> русского языка)

И даже - [стаккатовый](https://www.stihi.ru/2018/12/14/8012).

> Ты поднимешь ресницы над нефритовым таинством взгляда,
>
> Увлекая под зыби мой жаждущий странствия ум,
>
> По протокам бурлящим в манящую власть водопада,
>
> Где в стаккатовый пульс обратится размеренный шум?

Answer (score 0):

**Череда**. Полоса белая, полоса чёрная, полоса белая... - череда белых полос.